Any way to iterate over a vector in reverse or forwards based on a condition?
I am trying to do the following:
const bool b_condition = false;
const auto begin = b_condition ? arr.cbegin() : arr.crbegin();
// Will likely be different than arr.size(). Simplified here for example
const int size = arr.size();

std::for_each_n(begin, size, [](const Data& d) {
    // ...
});

I have to print the last or first size elements of a vector. Whether it is the last or first depends on b_condition.
const auto begin = b_condition ? arr.cbegin() : arr.crbegin();

The above code of course does not work as const_reverse_iterator and const_iterator are different types and only one can be stored in a variable.
After some research there does not seem to be a common base class for iterators so I cannot use that. Additionally, I understand this is extremely easy to do with a normal (non-std) for loop but I am trying to see if I can accomplish this with the standard library so I would prefer a std based answer.
Is there any way to iterate over the last or first size elements based on a condition with <algorithms>?

I've never seen the point of using std::for_each and I still don't.

@PasserBy std::execution::...?

@PasserBy I agree completely! But I do think there is some use in being able to use a large subset of the language's features. I wanted to attempt this because this is trivial with c-style for loops and seems to be something I should be able to do with std::for_each_n.

@TedLyngmo Fine, I'll give you that. I was thinking of the cases where it's just a replacement for regular loops, as in the case here.

@TedLyngmo execution policies only support parallel-looping and sequential-looping. I don't think there is anything for my use case here.

@PasserBy actually, something worth noting: they make multithreading loops easy. Although I must admit I have never actually seen that be used.

@Eshy "I have never actually seen that be used" - What was the C++17 (or later) option you saw used instead?

On topic: Why do you find the conditional operator crucial in this scenario? Why not: if(condition) { /* do this */ } else { /* do that */ }?

@TedLyngmo I meant that I haven't seen every single iteration of a loop be parallelized before. I have seen code handling parsing large image files in chunks. The parallelization was handled manually there though. The file was split into chunks based on the file's size and each chunk was combined at the end. That said I am not a profession or anything (you can probably tell by the question).

@Eshy Execution policies typically work well if applied on an outer loop. The nitty-gritty parts inside will typically be hand crafted, and if done properly, no external synchronization will be needed.

@TedLyngmo because I like keeping things const unless they need to be mutable. The other way to initialize begin would be a immediately invoked lambda, which seems overkill here.
If you mean why I don't just make two for loops then that is because, as I understand, the point of the standard library is to make code expressive and compact. It would make much more sense to just use a c-style loop if my only other option is to write double the code.
The motivation behind my question is to learn whether there is a standard-library way to do this. I am not suggesting this is best practice.

@TedLyngmo That is a very good point! I just do not have the experience in cpp to have run into that situation. I will keep that in the back of my mind though!

"why I don't just make two for loops" - You can write one loop that instantiated becomes two loops. When it comes to the standard library, the use of it often becomes a function template.

@TedLyngmo Sorry, I am not sure I fully grok what you mean. Do you mean to abstract the loop into a templated function and execute it with a different template argument based on the condition?

@Eshy "templated function" - Yes, except, there are no templated functions. There are only function templates. It's a language detail that makes a big difference when it comes to explaining instantiations.

@TedLyngmo I see. I might stick to the c-style implementation then. Having two functions, one a function template seems very much unreasonable here. Thank you for you discussion!

@Eshy You're welcome. If you provide the working C-style implementation @ codereview and tag it C++, someone may provide an alternative that doesn't seem unreasonable.

You'd have to make a new templated function to do the iteration to deal with the types being different. You can shortcut this slightly by using a lambda:
const bool b_condition = false;

const int size = arr.size();
auto iterate = [&](auto begin) {
  std::for_each_n(begin, size, [](const Data& d) {
    //print d
  });
};
if (b_condition)
{
  iterate(arr.cbegin());
}
else 
{
  iterate(arr.crbegin());
}

